# php: What is a static class variable's behaviour when a same class object with different value of the static variable is read from a file?

Tags: php, file, class, variables, static

**Here's the idea:** I'm building a file upload site in php where the records of users are stored in a flat file as an array of objects of class User. In the structure of the User class i have defined $iUsers as a static variable so as to count the number of users, without the need to have a separate records_number file.

**The experiment:** Suppose some first visitor Joe registers, logs in and does stuff. His version of $iUsers is 1 since he is the only user. Meanwhile other visitors register as well. So after Joe has uploaded a file, an update_user_activity function is triggered by ajax, which will attempt to read the records_file and update it.

**My question:** What happens when the objects' array is read from the file? Does User::$iUsers remains unchanged, does it gets the file's class static variable (for example 6, if 5 more visitors have registered), or gains some obscure, undefined value?

EDIT:
here is a sample of the class implementation as requested:

```
class User {
// user details, username, password, e-mail
static private $iUsers=0;
public function __construct($usr, $pwd, $eml) {
    //initializes user details
    $iUsers++;
}

// reads records from records file and locks the records file
static private function read_records(&$arr) {
    //lock file?
    //if User::check_connected()(checks session var) update $arr for the current user
    //open REC_FILE
    //unserialize to $arr
    //close REC_FILE
}
// Updates records from records file to the given array
static private function update_records(&$arr) {
    //unlock file
    //open REC_FILE
    //serialize $arr to file
    //close REC_FILE
}

static private function unlock_records() {
    //unlock file
}

// update function
private function update_user_activity() {
    read_records($recs);
    foreach($recs as $cur) {
        if($cur->sUsername === $this->sUsername) {
            //stuff here (updates the $cur
            update_records($recs);
            return true;
        }
    }
    unlock_records();
    return false;
}
static public function register(&$usr, &$pwd, &$eml) {
    //$recs array of records
    read_records($recs);
    if(iUsers<MAX_USERS) {
        // loop through the records --- unlocks_records and returns error if same name or e-mail is found
        $newuser = new User($usr, $pwd, $eml);
        array_push($recs, $newuser);
        update_records($recs);
        return "success";
    }
    else {
        unlock_records();
        return "No capacity for new users!";
    }
}

// login function
static public function login(&$usr, &$pw) {
    //$recs array of records
    read_records($recs);
    if(User::$iUsers>0) {
        foreach($recs as $cur) {
            if($cur->check_matching($usr, $pw)) {
                if($cur->$bActivated) {
                    // logged in
                    // stuff
                    update_records($recs);
                    return $cur;   //return whatever is going to be stored in _SESSION array;
                }
                else {
                    unlock_records();
                    return "Your account is deactivated!";
                }
            }
        }
        unlock_records();
        return "The username or password provided is wrong.";
    }
    else {
        unlock_records();
        return "There are no users registered!"; // no users registered
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you have som code that could demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're doing or your implementation, but if I recall correctly it's going to depend on how you access your files and whether or not you are synchronizing access via locking, else you're going to hit race conditions.

Comment: Don't store the count in the objects being counted.

Comment: Do you want to store counter of logged users in file and read/update it when user do something?

Comment: @Zarathuztra the point is that when update_user_activity() is called the reading of the records_file could contain a different version of the User::$iUsers, probably a higher int than the supposed login user's class static variable.

Comment: @meandmyjohnson You'll need to ensure you're synchronizing access to that file then. Try synchronized threads (and as with all threading, be careful) http://www.php.net/manual/en/thread.synchronized.php

Comment: @piotrekkr no. I'd like to store counter of registered users in file and at the same time update status (time last seen) for each user by interacting with the very same file (reading it and writing it).

Comment: @Zarathuztra oh well, I'm so much unfamilliar with threads that I'd rather use a separate count file and play a little more with file locks. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @meandmyjohnson Yup, sure thing! Bottom line is race conditions are going to be your worst enemy here it sounds like.

Comment: @Zarathuztra even for a site of 10 users max? I've read somewhere that planning for less than 100 users is not likely to demand a database. Now I don't claim to have superior experience or something nor I meant to be ironic. However, it seems to me that the possibility of concurrency issues is quite small.

Comment: @meandmyjohnson That's a risk analysis task my friend :)

Comment: @meandmyjohnson have you ever considered using `sqlite`? `SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine`. You could make a table for users and operate on it. Problem with file locking/unlocking is solved by sqlite.

Comment: @piotrekkr yes I've heard of it but never actually used it. My thoughts were that SQLite couldn't make much of a difference in terms of binding server resources compared to MySQL or MSSQL. Plus I was too "bored" to build the appropriate functions to prevent sql injections. So maybe I run a test version of the site, try to send to many requests to cause race conditions and after having succeeded change to sqlite :p

Comment: @meandmyjohnson don't know what you mean by `much of a difference in terms of binding server resources`. Sqlite database is just one file on disk, it does not have any server/client architecture. Why would you say that is more or less the same as MySQL/MSSQL? You don't need to `build the appropriate functions to prevent sql injections` because there is already `PDO::quote()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: @piotrekkr I guess you're right, I'm just a few years behind. I may give it a try.